# Working of Burp

Tags: http, session-management, burp-suite

I want to know How does burp decides whether the attack has been successful or not.

When I send a request through burp the server give http response code as 500, what does this mean

1. Session lost
2. Attack failed
3. Attack Succeeded to hamper the working of application
4. The security filter in the application stopped the attack

and what should be the ideal response code in case successful or unsuccessful attack?

Comment: Short answer, it depends

Comment: We have 0 information to help you answer this. We don't know what was sent, what was expected or what the true nature of the error is.

Answer (score 1):

500 - is internal server error so as one of the comments said it depends.

You should really understand what the appplication you are attacking is expected to do given different inputs. I.e. you need to map out what a lost session looks like, what attack succeeded looks like etc. Or at least as good ass it gets. When you have done this you can often separate the different cases by looking at the response and different details, i.e. content-length headers etc.

Without more information it is difficult to give you a better answer.

I would have installed a test-version of the product and performed the different tests in my own environment first. This way you can learn a lot about what happens in the application given different inputs and how to differ between the cases.

( Anyway if you don't have access to the logs you should consider the ethics portion of your testing ( unless performing black box test ) then you should have known this already. )

Comment: I have access to access logs, Can you tell me what more information you need to answer this question

Comment: You need to check yourself what is actually happening on the serverside when the 500-error is delivered to the browser. Hopefully this will help you understand which case you are in and thus you can identify/recognize it later.